# How to get the latest telegram channel post in PHP?

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot

How can I get the last telegram channel post in PHP?

For example, I can get the channel member count with this:

```
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=@channelusername");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, directly.
To do that you have to use `$update['channel_post']['message_id']` then store it into your database.